# C pass int array pointer as parameter into a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I want to pass the B int array pointer into func function and be able to change it from there and then view the changes in main function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *B[10]){

}

int main(void){

    int *B[10];

    func(&B);

    return 0;
}
```

the above code gives me some errors:

```
In function 'main':|
warning: passing argument 1 of 'func' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int * (*)[10]'|
```

**EDIT:
new code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *B){
    *B[0] = 5;
}

int main(void){

    int B[10] = {NULL};
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);
    func(B);
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

now i get these errors:

```
||In function 'func':|
|4|error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')|
||In function 'main':|
|9|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
|9|warning: (near initialization for 'B[0]') [enabled by default]|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 2 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Well, the error message explains it. You pass a pointer to an array of 10 `int *`, but `func` expects an `int**` (which is expected to be a pointer to the first element of an array of (10, presumably) `int*`s). How to fix it depends on what `func` does.

Comment: func will simply edit B values like B[0], B[1] etc..

Comment: Then you probably want to pass just `B`. Since `B` is actually an array, passing `&B` is typically not useful, since `B` can't be changed (but its contents can be changed, and that's what you want to do).

Comment: updated question with new code with errors when i try to edit an value of B in func function

Comment: The answer to your original question is that `func` should be declared like this: `int func(int (*B)[10])`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your new code,

```
int func(int *B){
    *B[0] = 5;
}
```

`B` is a pointer to `int`, thus `B[0]` is an `int`, and you can't dereference an `int`. Just remove the `*`,

```
int func(int *B){
    B[0] = 5;
}
```

and it works.

In the initialisation

```
int B[10] = {NULL};
```

you are initialising an`int` with a `void*` (`NULL`). Since there is a valid conversion from `void*` to `int`, that works, but it is not quite kosher, because the conversion is implementation defined, and usually indicates a mistake by the programmer, hence the compiler warns about it.

```
int B[10] = {0};
```

is the proper way to 0-initialise an `int[10]`.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you were trying to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int * B){

    /* B + OFFSET = 5 () You are pointing to the same region as B[OFFSET] */
    *(B + 2) = 5;
}

int main(void) {

    int B[10];

    func(B);

    /* Let's say you edited only 2 and you want to show it. */
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i try to edit B[2] in func i get some errors... code: `*B[2] = 5;`

Comment: @fxuser: "I get some errors" is not a useful problem description.  Ask for help as if you were the person being asked.  You are getting an error because `B` is a pointer to `int` and `B[2]` returns an int, not a pointer.  So, you just want `B[2] = 5;`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Why would you do `array + 2` instead of `array[2]`?

Answer (score 8):

If you actually want to pass an array pointer, it's

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int (*B)[10]){   // ptr to array of 10 ints.
        (*B)[0] = 5;   // note, *B[0] means *(B[0])
         //B[0][0] = 5;  // same, but could be misleading here; see below.
}

int main(void){

        int B[10] = {0};   // not NULL, which is for pointers.
        printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);
        func(&B);            // &B is ptr to arry of 10 ints.
        printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);

        return 0;
}
```

But as mentioned in other answers, it's not that common to do this. Usually a pointer-to-array is passed only when you want to pass a 2d array, where it suddenly looks a lot clearer, as below. A 2D array is actually passed as a pointer to its first row.

```
void func( int B[5][10] )  // this func is actually the same as the one above! 
{
         B[0][0] = 5;
}

int main(void){
    int Ar2D[5][10];
    func(Ar2D);   // same as func( &Ar2D[0] )
}
```

The parameter of func may be declared as `int B[5][10]`, `int B[][10]`,  `int (*B)[10]`, all are equivalent as parameter types.

Addendum: you can return a pointer-to-array from a function, but the syntax to declare the function is very awkward, the [10] part of the type has to go after the parameter list:

```
int MyArr[5][10];
int MyRow[10];

int (*select_myarr_row( int i ))[10] { // yes, really
   return (i>=0 && i<5)? &MyArr[i] : &MyRow;
}
```

This is usually done as below, to avoid eyestrain:

```
typedef int (*pa10int)[10];

pa10int select_myarr_row( int i ) {
   return (i>=0 && i<5)? &MyArr[i] : &MyRow;
}
```

Comment: And I note that C++  is getting templateable typedefs, so it should be possible to write  ptr_to_arr_of<int,10> select_myarr_row ... .

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `*(B)` instead of `*B[0]`.
Here,  `*(B+i)` implies `B[i]` and `*(B)` implies `B[0`], that is 
`*(B+0)=*(B)=B[0]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *B){
    *B = 5;     
    // if you want to modify ith index element in the array just do *(B+i)=<value>
}

int main(void){

    int B[10] = {};
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);
    func(B);
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In new code assignment should be,

```
B[0] = 5
```

In func(B), you are just passing address of the pointer which is pointing to array B. You can do change in func() as B[i] or *(B + i). Where i is the index of the array.

In the first code the declaration says,

```
int *B[10]
```

says that B is an array of 10 elements, each element of which is a pointer to a int. That is, B[i] is a int pointer and *B[i] is the integer it points to the first integer of the i-th saved text line.

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    int *arr[5];
    int i=31, j=5, k=19, l=71, m;

    arr[0]=&i;
    arr[1]=&j;
    arr[2]=&k;
    arr[3]=&l;
    arr[4]=&m;

    for(m=0; m<=4; m++)
    {
        printf("%d",*(arr[m]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the really excellent example from Greggo, I got this to work as a bubble sort with passing an array as a pointer and doing a simple -1 manipulation.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sub_one(int (*arr)[7])
{
     int i; 
     for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        (*arr)[i] -= 1 ; // subtract 1 from each point
        printf("%i\n", (*arr)[i]);

    }

}   

int main()
{
    int a[]= { 180, 185, 190, 175, 200, 180, 181};
    int pos, j, i;
    int n=7;
    int temp;
    for (pos =0; pos < 7; pos ++){
        printf("\nPosition=%i Value=%i", pos, a[pos]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
        temp=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((temp<a[j])&&(j>=0)) // while selected # less than a[j] and not j isn't 0
        {
            a[j+1]=a[j];    //moves element forward
            j=j-1;
        }
         a[j+1]=temp;    //insert element in proper place
    }

    printf("\nSorted list is as follows:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nmedian = %d\n", a[3]);
    sub_one(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

I need to read up on how to encapsulate pointers because that threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of func is accepting double-pointer variable.
Hope this helps...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int **B){

}

int main(void){

    int *B[10];

    func(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the function declaration you have to type as

```
VOID FUN(INT *a[]);
/*HERE YOU CAN TAKE ANY FUNCTION RETURN TYPE HERE I CAN TAKE VOID AS THE FUNCTION RETURN  TYPE FOR THE FUNCTION FUN*/
//IN THE FUNCTION HEADER WE CAN WRITE AS FOLLOWS
void fun(int *a[])
//in the function body we can use as
a[i]=var
```