# Pointer to const in function call

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I’ve an integer array `int foo[3]` and I want to pass it to another function. I would like to accomplish two things:

- Pass it by reference
- Set it as constant as it should not be modified.

The function I’ve defined is:

```
void print_foo(const int(*const foo)[3]) {

    // Print the second integer
    printf("%d\n", (*foo)[1]);
}
```

And I call it as:

```
int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};

print_foo(&foo);
```

When I compile it with MinGW’s gcc I get the warning:

```
warning: passing arg 1 of `print_foo` from incompatible pointer type
```

I would like to understand what am I doing wrong.

**Note:**
I can hide the warning declaring the function without the first `const` as:

```
void print_foo(int(*const foo)[3])
```

But this seems like a workaround as I want not only the pointer address to be constant but also the contents of the memory (that’s the reason of the two `const`).

Comment: I'm don't think it's related to your problem but in `“%d\n”` those are the wrong quotes. You need `"` instead. But maybe you are using the right quotes and it's the copy/pasting that changed those quotes (in which case you should copy/paste directly from the IDE to your browser without going through a word processor first).

Comment: You are right, I’m asking with the iPad and there is a problem with the quotes. I’ll edit it.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730786/c-pass-int-array-pointer-as-parameter-into-a-function perhaps help?

Comment: If you want to pass by reference then why not pass by reference? `void print_foo(const int( & foo )[3])`

Comment: which version of gcc is that ?

Comment: and : C++ or C ?

Comment: I don’t known the version of the compiler. I think MinGW is a Windows wrapper for gcc. And It is C.

Comment: @Octan C doesn't have references

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to array with const qualifier in C & C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488559/pointer-to-array-with-const-qualifier-in-c-c)

Comment: also : [Const correctness for array pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199473/const-correctness-for-array-pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I could compile the following code with CLang versions 3.4.1 and 6.0.0 with no warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_foo(const int (* const foo)[3]) {
    printf("%d - size: %lu\n", (*foo)[1], sizeof(*foo));
}
int main() {
    int foo[3] = {1,2,3};
    print_foo(&foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `2 - 12` on my 32 bits system, which proves that `sizeof(*foo)` has the expected value.

But I would say that gcc is correct here, and that Clang allows it as an extension.

The standard (draft n1570 for C11) says at 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type §1:

> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for
>   determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for declarators and in 6.7.3 Type qualifiers § 10
>
> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type

So types need to have the same constness to be compatible.

But passing parameters in a function call has the same semantics as an assignment, and 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment says in its constraints:

> One of the following shall hold:
> ...
>   the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right

So ok, it is allowed to assign an `int (*)[3]` to an `int (const *)[3]` even if they are not compatibles.

But `int [3]` and `const int[3]` are different types, so you cannot assign an `int (*)[3]` to a `const int (*)[3]` nor to a `const int (const *)[3]`.

What you want makes sense, but I cannot imagine a conformant way to declare it.

Comment: gcc also has it as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointers-to-Arrays.html), but I suspect the OP doesn't use a gcc version that has this (or is using `-pedantic-errors`).

Comment: Yes, the warning is not shown when I compile with Visual Studio but it appears compiling with MinGW (which is the official compiler)

Comment: It’s curious, though, that the compiler doesn’t warn me when I cast structs to `const` in functions like `void func(const StructName * const foo)`. I assume the main difference here is that in this case there is no array involved.

Comment: Very concise explanation. You might want to quote C17 instead of C11.

Answer (score 3):

just do that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

// note can also use "const int foo[3]" but in that
// case 3 is nothing more than a comment for a reader
void print_foo(const int foo[])
{
  // Print the second integer
  printf("%d\n", foo[1]);
}

int main()
{
  int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};

  print_foo(foo);
}
```

the array is already given by address

Comment: This will not check array size though because array will decay to normal pointer. `int foo[1]{1}; print_foo(foo);`

Comment: This means that including the `[3]` array in the argument definition already makes it a pointer? I thought that It shall be an empty braces: `const int foo[]`, without the 3.

Comment: @Octan using "[]" or "[3]" in hte signature of `print_foo` changes nothing for the compiler, is just a kind of comment saying the size is 3

Comment: It is misleading to specify a size in `void print_foo(const int foo[3])` because it is completely ignored by the compiler. Either write `void print_foo(const int foo[])` or `void print_foo(const int *foo)`

Comment: If you want to specify 3 as a comment, write it in a comment. `[3]` is confusing for beginners. As a matter of fact, the function works for any array size greater than 1.

Comment: @chqrlie in a way you are saying the compiler is confusing allowing that ^^ But in fact I agree with you, I just come from the user code ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie I am new to c and i have a doubt from the comment you mentioned above why will compiler ignore the 3 in array ? trying to learn.

Comment: @heeat replace `[3]` by `[1]` in the signature and you will see you will continue to access to `foo[1]` without warning ;-)

Comment: Ok so you are saying that in the compiler side there is no difference between `const int foo[]` and something like `const int (*const foo)[3]`. I just wanted to state that **only** size 3 arrays are accepted as an input.

Comment: Indeed the C language allows for many confusing constructs and compilers should issue many more warnings by default, most of which should be errors. This would save so many hours wasted in debugging stupid mistakes. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` is first step.

Comment: @chqrlie because of the protests on the [3] even accompanied by the commentary I replaced it with [] ;-)

Comment: @Octan: OK, but you pass the address of an array of 3 `int` that is not `const`, hence the type mismatch. It is not idiomatic in C to specify function signatures in such a restrictive way.

Comment: Thanks. I need MISRA-C compliance and I wanted to be really specific on the input type: constant pointer, with constant contents and array size of 3. However I’ve tried the tree options and the variable is always modifiable even the `const`.

Comment: @Octan the array is already given by address, you do not need to add a level of pointer, just using `const int foo[]` you have what finally you want, you cannot modify the array